# Changing paragraph spacing within an item using paralist

Tags: spacing, paralist

I am using compactenum in the paralist package. I wish to have spacing between paragraphs within an item, but no additional spacing between items. The option:

\plparsep: Space between paragraphs within an item the parskip for
this environment.

seems like this should be it. But using this also produces space between two items. How can I get additional vertical space but only within an item?

MWE

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage{paralist}
\plparsep 0.2in

\begin{document}
  \begin{compactenum}
   \item foo

   bar

   \item foo
   \item bar
  \end{compactenum}
\end{document}
```

As written, I get the spacing within the first item like I want, but I also get additional spacing between the 2nd and 3rd items. Commenting out \plparsep 0.2in gives exactly the opposite: no spacing within the first item and no spacing between the 2nd and 3rd items.

Comment: Something like this? `\plparsep=0.2in \plitemsep=-0.2in`

Comment: @Malipivo: I thought of doing something along those lines, but it felt like more of a hack to me. Going through the documentation more thoroughly, it seems like this is the only decent solution using compactenum. I'd accept this as an answer.

Comment: We could modify it to you needs, but in that case you must describe it more precisely. Also there are some other packages capable of handling itemize lists.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We used `\plparsep=0.2in` and negative value in `\plitemsep`: `\plitemsep=-0.2in`. For now this is our result.

```
%! *latex mal-spacing.tex
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\pagestyle{empty}
\usepackage{paralist}
\plparsep=0.2in
\plitemsep=-0.2in
\begin{document}
Text before.
  \begin{compactenum}
   \item foo\par
   bar1\par
   bar2\par
   \item foo
   \item bar
  \end{compactenum}
Text after.
\end{document}
```

[image: mwe]

Answer (score 1):

You can have the same result with the `enumitem`package, which is much more versatile.

Here are two examples, in which I chose to make the label indentation equal to paragraph indentation:

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{report}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[textheight = 24cm]{geometry}
\pagestyle{empty}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\setlist[enumerate, 1]{labelindent=\parindent, labelwidth=0.5em, leftmargin=!, align=left}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]
  \begin{enumerate}[noitemsep, parsep = 0.5cm, itemsep = -\parsep ]
   \item foo\par
   bar1\par
   bar2\par
   \item foo
   \item bar
  \end{enumerate}

  \lipsum[2]
  \begin{enumerate}[nosep, parsep = 1cm, itemsep = -\parsep ]
   \item foo\par
   bar1\par
   bar2\par
   \item foo
   \item bar
  \end{enumerate}

  \lipsum[3]

\end{document}
```

[image]